# Grouped records with aggregate fields

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm running an instance of Solr 6.2. One of the use cases I'm exploring is to return records grouped by a field, including summed columns (facets) and sorted by those columns. I realize Solr is not meant to be utilized as a relational database, but is this possible?

Using the JSON API, I send the following data payload to the `query` endpoint of my Solr instance:

```
{
  query: "*:*",
  filter: ["status:1", "date:[2016-10-11T00:00:00Z-7DAYS/DAY TO 2016-10-11T00:00:00Z]"],
  limit: 10,
  params: {
    group: true,
    group.field: name,
    group.facet: true
  },
  facet: {
    funcs: {
      type: terms,
      field: name,
      sort: { sum_v1: desc },
      limit: 10,
      facet: {
        sum_v1: "sum(v1)",
        sum_v2: "sum(v2)",
        sum_v3: "sum(v3)"
      }
    }
  }
```

This returns 10 records at a time in both the `groups` key and `facets` key of the response JSON. However, the sorted facet buckets do not match up with the grouped records. How can I get the facet counts **with** the relevant groups?

The only workaround I can come up with is to do a query for the grouped records first, then do another query using the `id`'s from that query to get the facet counts. However, the downside is that I'd lose the ability to sort or filter by any of the facet counts.